# Specify the sort-order for an Enum field type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model that uses the `Enum` field type:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum, Integer, String

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    summary = Column(String)
    priority = Column(Enum('low', 'medium', 'high'))
```

If I sort the records by priority (the Enum), it's sorts alphabetically:

```
high
low
medium
```

How can I specify the sort-order for this field?

Comment: What database are you using under the covers?

Comment: postgres, but a database agnostic solution is preferable.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Even though PostgreSQL supports enum type and ordering, my ORM doesn't (Knex). It just created a varchar column.

Comment: SQLAlchemy 1.4 and Postgresql 11. I'm seeing the opposite. `level = sqla.Column(sqla.Enum("INFO", "ERROR", "WARNING", name="level")) `Results are sorted by list order already, not alphabetical order. I wouldn't know how to enforce alphabetical (if not by sorting the list alphabetically).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way may exist, but the simplest (and most database-agnostic) solution I know of would be to use a [`case` statement](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) in the `order by` clause.

**First**, set up your `whens` dict for your case statement by getting the tuple you used to create the column's `Enum`:

```
enums = Task.priority.type.enums  # finds the Enum tuple (with the same order you originally gave it)
whens = {priority: index for index, priority in enumerate(enums)}  # dynamically creates whens dict based on the order of the Enum tuple
```

Or, if you must, hard code your `whens` dict (definitely less than ideal, since you now have to change code in two places):

```
whens = {'low': 0, 'medium': 1, 'high': 2}
```

**Second**, set up your sort logic in a case statement:

```
sort_logic = case(value=Task.priority, whens=whens).label("priority")
```

**Third**, run your query and order by your case statement:

```
q = session.query(Task).order_by(sort_logic)  # see the sql at the end of this answer
```

You now have a query sorted by your original `Enum` tuple:

```
>>> for item in q:
        print item.id, item.priority
#  now in the order you were looking for
4 low
7 low
3 medium
8 medium
2 high
6 high
```

Just for reference, the above query produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT        tasks.id AS tasks_id,
              tasks.summary AS tasks_summary,
              tasks.priority AS tasks_priority 
FROM          tasks
ORDER BY CASE tasks.priority
             WHEN :param_1 THEN :param_2
             WHEN :param_3 THEN :param_4
             WHEN :param_5 THEN :param_6
         END
```